# Possible conflict of Ubuntu security software with Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser

after brilliantly solving the main problem that my Ubuntu Power had, from my friend Chili555, I wanted to submit another small problem that my Ubuntu has, this time on the Firefox browser. I understood that here it is also a conflict between software but I don't know how to solve it. In practice, every time Firefox starts, a red line appears telling me that the Firefox bookmark will not work properly and therefore will be disabled, because there is a problem that probably has to do with the security software. So from what I understand, the Ubuntu security software, which is different from other distros, in fact in the other distros this problem does not exist, it conflicts with the part of Firefox dedicated to bookmarks and therefore to the saving of the latter or to the management of these. I tried to disable the Ubuntu security software but nothing has changed, I tried to perform a procedure that describes the Firefox guide, where it says to try to delete directories and restart the browser but nothing even in this case. So what do you think is happening exactly in this Firefox, which prevents the regular operation? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. Is the behavior the same for every site that you try to access or just one? Can you ping the site? `ping -c3 http://www.somesite.com`

Comment: Hi chili, no the behavior is of the browser, independent of the site you visit.The problem I think is the browser itself, when you start it, it gives you the error, I see that it does it at the browser level right, at startup ...

Comment: Can you start it from the terminal? `firefox` Are there any helpful clues in the terminal output? If the result is lengthy, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Ok but I need to know the precise command because I have never started it from the terminal being installed in a classic way. Can you tell me the command to start it from the terminal? I start Chromium from the terminal because I don't have it installed in the classic way but I downloaded the directory with all the necessary files inside, which I found on the gitlab site and once inside this directory I execute ./chrome and it starts from the terminal .. .

Comment: The exact command is: `firefox` It will show quite a few lines of which many will not be significant errors.

Comment: here is the output when I start firefox from the terminal, I see gpu errors but I don't know if they are related to the problem encountered and in any case even when I was not using the rx 5700 xt, the problem was always the same ...

Comment: Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: More than 1 GPU detected via PCI, cannot deduce vendor (t=1.54919) [GFX1-]: More than 1 GPU detected via PCI, cannot deduce vendor
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: More than 1 GPU detected via PCI, cannot deduce vendor (t=1.54919) |[1][GFX1-]: PCI candidate 0x1a03/0x2000 (t=1.54925) [GFX1-]: PCI candidate 0x1a03/0x2000

Comment: Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: More than 1 GPU detected via PCI, cannot deduce vendor (t=1.54919) |[1][GFX1-]: PCI candidate 0x1a03/0x2000 (t=1.54925) |[2][GFX1-]: PCI candidate 0x1002/0x731f (t=1.54927) [GFX1-]: PCI candidate 0x1002/0x731f

Comment: It tells me it detects more than one GPU but it is normal as I have both AMD's external gpu and the one built into the motherboard. I've never had a problem with this, not even in the other distros I use, can I believe there is such a problem on Ubuntu? I do not know

Comment: I believe the problem is Firefox, not Ubuntu. Here is a helpful link: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1692024 Studying...

Comment: May we see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0300 -A3`

Comment: But the strange thing is that this type of problem only occurs when using Firefox on Ubuntu. If I use it on Fedora or Debian, this problem does not happen and even then I always have the same GPU configuration ... It all seems strange to me ...

Comment: Did you try this from the bug report? `GDK_BACKEND=wayland firefox`? Did you try Chromium?

Comment: What exactly should I do, what is the exact procedure?  I have never done these bug reports ... Chrome works perfectly, the only thing that the version for our processor is not directly installable, at the moment I use the compiled source and after I enter the directory I open the terminal and start the executable to do it start

Comment: I am trying to understand through guides on the internet how to install Chromium correctly and have it available without having to do that procedure from source every time ... otherwise Chromium is great, for Power architecture it is the best as a browser

Comment: I just managed to create the desktop shortcut for Chromium, now I can start it from a regular icon like all other applications. For Firefox I just wanted to understand why it has this problem and if nothing more could be solved, in the end it is not essential as it was the network attention ... :-)